# Connect Android Emulator to internet, using script in internet explorer

Tags: android, internet-explorer, android-emulator

I used:

```
emulator -avd emulatorname -dns-server 10.155.21.206
```

I got the error:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools>DNS server name '10.155.21.206' resolved to 10.155.21.206:55 emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Unknown error
```

I tried `8.8.8.8` also. That didnt work either, gave me a similar error.

Im using a script to connect to the internet in `internet explorer but no proxy`.

Could company policies have something to do with this error?

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't create necessary ports on you machine. Yes it can be blocked by local machine policy.